# Youtube v2 to v3 migration in Android apps

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, migration

My Android application was using the youtube v2 api to get the list of videos of a public profile like this one:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/USER_PROFILE_NAME/videos?view=0&flow=list
```

I got the free json response and used it to get the links and video titles.
Now api v2 gets deprecated and from what I see there is not easy way to get the videos list. Has anyone used api v3 to get the list of videos? Is there any easy tutorial for the java library? Importing the full youtube library seems overkill as I just want the list of videos with their titles. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the google api client for java, there's a great example to do exactly what you want (list a user's videos) here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

If you think that's overkill, you could just use an HTTP request library and make a couple of API calls; first call the "channels" endpoint to get the playlist ID:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={YOUTUBE_USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

That will return an "uploads" playlist, which you can then grab and do an API call to the playlistItems endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={THE_PLAYLIST_ID_YOU_RETRIEVED}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In that last call, you could also use the 'fields' parameter if you want to leave out returning of info like the video descriptions.

Comment: Although I found the solution before this post. It is the correct one, so I will accept the answer. Note for the next people...as "API KEY" I used from the Developer console, "Credentials" link, a Simple API Access key and then used the "Server key" button ( with no IP filtering ).